# No bcrypt implementation in iOS... can use other language, create static library?

Tags: c#, java, objective-c, hash, bcrypt

There is no straight forward bCrypt ( http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) implementation in Objective-C, and while there are C code that does accomplish this, it's specifically for x86 processors, relying on BSD libraries.

I'm building an iOS app which shares the same password hashes as corresponding Online (.NET and HTML5+Javascript) applications.

I'm not quite where I ought to be, where I can read the awfully simplistic Java code ( http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) and translate it to Objective-C code, suitable for iOS development.

However, there is a Ruby implementation ( https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby), and I've heard that you can use Ruby to build iOS applications. Could I then roll the Ruby code up into a Static Library, and link it to my iOS projects? Or, even use Mono and utilize the .NET implementation (also a clean, pure-code, no-dependency project) to build a Static Library?

Or, finally, does anyone know of an Objective-C implementation of the bCrypt code? It seems simple enough, I just don't know enough about .NET/C#/Ruby to translate it myself.

Comment: The ruby version actually uses the BSD based C code (https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/ext/mri/bcrypt.c) or the java code you mention for jruby (https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/ext/jruby/bcrypt_jruby/BCrypt.java) so using that wouldn't really help you anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have recently open sourced my own BCrypt Objective C implementation.  I too looked for an existing Objective C implementation but to no avail.  So I ported one from Java instead!

It does not have any external library or framework dependencies so it might be the perfect fit for you.

You can find it here...
<del>http://www.jayfuerstenberg.com/blog/bcrypt-in-objective-c</del> https://github.com/jayfuerstenberg/JFCommon

Comment: Great work for the library thanks! I'm having a problem though as the app freezes when calling hashPassword: withSalt:. Are you aware of this? Thanks

Comment: Either a freeze or it takes a very long time to process... Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Yes BCrypt takes a lot of time to compute a hash, especially if you use a high number of rounds.  But this is what makes it secure.  You'll need to find the right trade off of performance and security for your app's needs.

Comment: -[__NSCFString appendString:]: getting crash when i used this used classes

Comment: @JasonFuerstenberg Error 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 4):

iOS has the Security.framework to handle such taks. See [Mac OS X and iOS Security Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/SecuritySvcs.html), and to store a secure password you would use [Certificate, Key and Trust Services,](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157) see example for how to [Encrypting and Decrypting Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9). The article you linked on bcrypt bears little value for devices programming as it is about how to store secure password on the *server* side. On a device you will always be the client the rules of how clients store passwords securely differ, as they are required to know the original password in almost all challenge protocols, and client side is exposed to completely different threat model that server side is.

Comment: I like this answer... wondering if it'll fly with the project manager. Mind if I quote you?

Answer (score 2):

Objective C can use C-libraries. Why bother with Ruby when https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt and http://www.openwall.com/crypt/ exist?

Comment: I'm getting linker errors.. not sure if it's because the rg3/bcrypt/crypt_blowfish.c can't fit into the platform...?
`Undefined symbols:
  "__BF_body_r", referenced from:
      __crypt_blowfish_rn in crypt_blowfish.o
      __crypt_blowfish_rn in crypt_blowfish.o
  "__BF_clean", referenced from:
      _clean in crypt_blowfish.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Works! (rg3/bcrypt). Not as slow as I'd thought, either. Just doesn't compile in Simulator.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll have to keep that in mind for when I get to iOS development.