# Equivalent of password_hash() in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I would like to send password to PHP for password verification. However, sending through plain text, MD5 or SHA1 are dangerous. Before I can use SSL / HTTPS, can I use something like PHP's `password_hash()` to encode the password before sending to PHP (so that I can use PHP's `password_verify()` to verify the password ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses the [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) algorithm. This is not natively supported by Objective-C, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6872592/4751173) provides a link to a library which implements it.

However, just like with MD5 and SHA1, you'll still be sending a hashed password over HTTP. The only difference is that it is much harder to crack the original password.

Comment: Thanks for the light. Implementing `BCrypt` looks harder than I think in Objective-C. SSL seems an easy way for me now.

Comment: Implementing `BCrypt` using the solution written by Jay Fuerstenberg is very easy and straightforward. You need only to import the header files and the `JFBCrypt` methods `generateSaltWithNumberOfRounds:` and `hashPassword:withSalt:`